# layering within an HTML inside a webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a html assets that show thanks to a webview in android. With current browsers is shown well, but with older browsers such as Android 2.1 goes what you see in the images.
[image: First image of my app][image: Fail]

I put the code in case anyone wants to see. 

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>
    <script>
        function show(divactual,textactual) {
            if(document.getElementById(divactual).style.display == "block"){
                document.getElementById(divactual).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(textactual).innerHTML = "show details...";

                }
            else if(document.getElementById(divactual).style.display == "none"){
                document.getElementById(divactual).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(textactual).innerHTML = "hidden details...";
                }
        }
    </script>   
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color:transparent;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.0em;
            font-style: normal;
            color:#999999;
            margin:10px;
        }
        body a{
            color:#0CF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #bg {
            z-index: -14;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #letrapequena {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.6em;
            color: #00537c;
        }
        #tituloseccion{
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#7AB800;
        }
        #headtwo{
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#7AB800;
        }
        #headthree{
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#00537C;
        }
        #container{
            background-color:#D8F7FE;
            margin:10px 0;
            color:#00537c;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:transparent;">
    <div id="tituloseccion">
        Titleone
    </div>
    <hr align="left" width="90%" size="0.1em" color="#999999">
    <div id="headtwo">titletwo</div>
    <div id="bigcontainer" style="display:block;">
        <div id="headthree">titlethree</div>
        <div id="generalcont" style="display:block;">
            <div id="container" style="display:block;">
                <div style="display:inline">parrone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                    <a href="javascript:show('info1','text1');" id="text1">show datails...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  id="info1" style="display:none;" >
                text text text text text text text text 
            </div>
         </div>

        <div id="generalcont" style="display:block;">
            <div id="container" style="display:block;">
                <div style="display:inline">parrtwo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                    <a href="javascript:show('info2','text2');" id="text2">show details...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  id="info2" style="display:none;" >
                text text text text text text text 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="letrapequena" style="display:block;">
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVA**

```
 package es.ibys.prueba.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class PruebawebviewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String miurl = "file:///android_asset/index2.htm";
        myWview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        myWview.loadUrl(miurl);
    }
}
```

I do not know how to fix it. I've tried be changing layer, css, div, styles ... everything that has occurred to me. Does anyone happened? How did you managed? Please help

Comment: How does the text that appears wrong get shown on the screen? And what are you trying to get it to do? Could you clarify a little.

Comment: Hi. When one of the texts unfold, those below, will remain on the screen where you were and the text is scrolled over them. This text should be displayed below the text does not get behind. I hope I have explained ;-)

Comment: So basically they're overlapping?

Comment: Yes they´re overlapping when I click in hidden/show details

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't a problem with your JS?

Here's a fiddle with your code in it: http://jsfiddle.net/8wsvu/

Is the `show()` function in pure JS an Android function, or is it supposed to be JS? I'm not great enough yet in JS to know if it is, but googling it turned up no results for it being a JS function.

My second guess as to why it's layering wrong is because the `div`'s are being absolute positioned on top of each other.

If you can use jQuery for showing and hiding the elements on the page, this would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I've tried with jquery and simple div, that is, inside a div no other. Still going on terminals with android 2.1 and below. thanks

Comment: hi, guys. Somebody know if i changing the html by html5, this problem is resolved? thanks

Comment: Hi Charlie. Your answer did not help :-(. The problem is still happening. For this reason I ask if changing html5 could solve the problem. thanks fo all

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. The problem have been solved in some terminals with html5, but in others the problem continue. Those terminal have a old version of browser. I think this is the problem. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Make sure you mark this as your answer if it answered your question.